# Distance in polynomial spaces

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials

I'm trying to solve some exercises proposed by ENS of Paris.
In particular the last one (which can be seen at http://www.ens.fr/IMG/file/SI2015/Sujets%20SCiences/Math2-version%20anglaise.pdf).

Since there are no solutions, I have a doubt!

I'm referring to second exercise.

1) In order to find $a_0$ I transformed the numerator as follows:

$(x-1)\cdot \dots \cdot (x-n) = (x+2-3)\cdot \dots \cdot (x-n) = (x+2)(x-2)\cdot \dots \cdot (x-n) + \dots$, where $\dots$ means the rest of the multiplication by $-3$. Then:

$=(x+2)(x+3-5)\cdot \dots \cdot (x-n) + \dots = (x+2)(x+3)\cdot \dots \cdot (x-n) + \dots$ and so on.

Then $a_0$ must be equal to $1$. Right?

For the second point I computed the integral of $T\cdot x^j$ for $1\leq j \leq n$ because if $T$ is orthogonal to the all generators, then it will be orthogonal to the whole space $F$. Then:

$\left< T, x^j \right> = \int_0^1\left( T(x) x^j  \right)dx = \dots = \frac{a_n}{n+j+1} + \dots + \frac{a_0}{j+1}$ and this is zero because for $x = j$ then $S(X)= 0$. Right?

May I have a hint for the (3)?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. Your computation of $a_0$ has an error. A quick way to find this value is to observe that $S(X) - \frac{a_0}{X+1}$ must be bounded near $X = -1$ and consequently $(X+1)S(X)-a_0$ must vanish at $X = -1$. . Thus $a_0 = \lim_{X \to -1} S(X)(X+1) = (-1)^n(n+1)$. As to part (3): The codimension of $F$ in $E$ is 1, so $F^\perp$ is spanned by a single polynomial, which you computed in part (2). Note also that the function $S$ may be expressed concisely in terms of Pochhammer symbols.

Comment: Good trick to compute $a_0$, thank you very much.
For the second you are right, indeed the dimension is 1 and then the only polynomial is $T$.
For the point (4)? I have to find the minimum of the distance between $P \in R_n[x]$ and $1$.
How can I compute that minimum?

Comment: You want to find a polynomial $P_0 \in F$ such that $\|P_0 - 1 \|^2 \le \|Q - 1\|^2$ for all $Q \in F$. This implies that $P_0-1 \perp F$ (prove this). Also $P_0$ is unique (prove this or look it up). Now check whether you can find $P_0$ from $T$, which has some of these properties.

Comment: Thank you, very very much!